# Correctly allocate stack for clone a thread

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, pthreads, glibc

So I want to create a thread without `CLONE_FILES flag`. I try to call clone directly, but has some strange problem. I think it is related to incorrect memory allocation.

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const int clone_flags = (CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_SYSVSEM
            | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD
            | CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID
            | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID
            | 0);

static int cloneThread(void* arg)
{
    long arg2 = (long)arg + (long)arg;
    long* arg2_ptr = &arg2;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int STACK_SIZE = 0x800000;
    void* stackaddr = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    void* stacktop  = (char*)stackaddr + STACK_SIZE; // assuming stack going downwards

    clone(cloneThread, stacktop, clone_flags, (void*)1);
    sleep(1); // wait for cloneThread running before exit
}
```

As you can see here, I am using malloc for stack allocation. `lldb` shows the program crashes at the beginning of `cloneThread`. But if I remove `long* arg2_ptr = &arg2;`, the program exit successfully.

I also read source code of `pthread_create.c`, `allocatestack.c`. With `strace`, I replaced `malloc` with the following

```
void* stackaddr = mmap(NULL, STACK_SIZE, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0);
mprotect(stackaddr, STACK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE);
```

But it has the same behavior as using malloc. So how should I use clone?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, g++ 7.3.0

Comment: By the way, I used lldb because gdb crashed previously. After resolving this issue, I am planning calling pthread_create in cloneThread, then I will have a normal pthread with FD table separate from the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you supply the `CLONE_SETTLS`, `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID` and `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` flags you must provide the `newtls`, `ptid` and `ctid` arguments to `clone()` respectively.

If all you want is a normal thread with a separate FD table though, just use `pthread_create()` and call `unshare(CLONE_FILES)` as the first operation in the new thread.

Comment: Beware that calling `unshare(CLONE_FILES)` from a multi-threaded program can have truly weired effects because many libraries (including parts of glibc) assume that file descriptors are process-global can be used from different threads.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems work well now after I removed CLONE_SETTLS, CLONE_PARENT_SETTID and CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID. I will try unshare(CLONE_FILES) if I have strange problem later in the future.